# Unramified extensions and base change

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, local-field, ramification

Let $K'/K$ be a finite extension of local discrete valued fields, and let $E/K$ be any extension of local discrete valued fields. Assume that $E\otimes_KK'$ is a field, and that $E\otimes_KK'/E$ is unramified. Is it true that $K'/K$ is unramified?

I think the answer should be yes, but unfortunately I cannot prove it. One can reduce to the case when $K'/K$ is totally ramified, and try to derive a contradiction from there.

Comment: Won't $[ \kappa(E \otimes_K K'):\kappa(E \otimes_K K)] \le [\kappa(K'):\kappa(K)]$ ? If so $[\kappa(K'):\kappa(K)] < [K':K] \implies [ \kappa(E \otimes_K K'):\kappa(E \otimes_K K)]  < [ E \otimes_K K':E \otimes_K K] $

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how to prove your first inequality.